# Send a mail on closing the browser tab

Tags: php, jquery, database, forms, email

I am currently working on a multistep form, and it has around 100 fields.

Suppose a user start filling the form and completed 30 fields and get harrased.
And suddenly the user closes the tab, then a pop up should open as shown in the image below.

Now user enter the email address in a pop up form, and on clicking button, a mail will be send with all the filled values (i.e. 30 fields value).

[image]

Is this possible in some other way or this way...Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `window.unload`: https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Make a call to the server through jQuery's `$.post`, and serialize the form data. You'll have to manage the data on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply..
but i am little bit confused.
is it possibble to open a form on unload event as shown in a image where user can  input the email address and click on send button.
Will you give a brief example for your above mention answer.
plz m requesting..Thank you.

Comment: Use a modal for the email address popup. Call that when the unload function fires. The contents (= the email form) of the modal you should already have rendered on the page (hidden), or retrieve it via Ajax when the  unload fires.

Comment: thank you ..MAVE.
Will give a try & let you know whether this issue was solved or not?

Comment: I have use this code
`$(window).unload(function() {
    alert("test");});`
but not working. I have included jquery and there was no conflict for $. No error in console even.

Comment: unload is a deprecated function of jQuery and has been removed in jQuery version 3.0